# Loading several images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Currently, I am creating a system to show random pictures every 0.5 seconds. I have almost 40k pictures +-

But, I am getting issues to load these pictures using Javascript.
1 - If I load them too fast, I got sometimes "cancelled" as response in console. (https://prnt.sc/1t23k2o)
2 - If I check if the image was successfully loaded to load the next image, I get an delay and this result in bottleneck showing images every 0.5 seconds. (onLoad)

```
(function getImages(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    v++;
    var r = Math.random();
    img.src = "seg/out-" + v + ".jpg?v=" + r;
    if (--i) getImages(i);
  }, 500)
})(300); // trigger this function 300x
```

How do I handle this? Could you help me improve my logic? Thank you.

Comment: You can try loading a specific amount of images and add pagination, or just wait for an `x` amount of images to be loaded and then continue loading the next ones. Also if you have a specific code issue you can add your code here so we can help better.

Comment: [Lazy loading](https://www.google.com/search?q=images+lazy+loading+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot help about the "cancelled" thing. An approach I'd consider would be tiling say 9 pictures into one - perhaps dynamically on the server? -  and downloading that (it would delay your initial `OnLoad`, however) then pulling in the next tile during the 4.5 seconds. All other things being equal, one 9Mb file tends to be faster than nine 1Mb files. Or pay for a CDN.

Comment: @PietroNadalini I cannot use pagination. I have updated my code, could you please write me a piece of code to load x amounf ot images? Or show any reference for this? Thank you.

Comment: @KenY-N the images is already stored in CDN

Comment: Use `async/await` and a `Promise`, or at the minimum catch the HTTP response header `200` before loading another image, to avoid funneling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pre-load an image at the end of the previous timeout, like that:

```
function preLoadImage(src) {
  const preloader = new Image();
  preloader.src = src;
}

function setImage(src) {
  img.src = src;
}

(function getImages(i, currentSrc) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    v++;
    setImage(currentSrc);

    const r = Math.random();
    const nextSrc = "seg/out-" + v + ".jpg?v=" + r;
    preLoadImage(nextSrc);

    if (--i) getImages(i, nextSrc);
  }, 500)
})(300);
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.